# use linear approximation to estimate $\arctan 1.1$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My attempt

Given the formula $f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)$

$\arctan'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}$

I don't know how to go on for this case, and I'm not allowed to use calculator.

Comment: $a$ has to be some point close to your number $x$ that you know the arctangent of, how about $a=1$?

Comment: Sorry but I'm very confused about this problem, why did you choose 1 ?

Comment: Because 1 is very close to 1.1 and the arctangent of 1 is an exact number $\arctan (1)=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Ok I'll try to solve